# i want call service from another Domain with AJAX and get CORS Error

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, web-services

i Use one .NET service and get HTML code From Service and Code has Script And use External Script   file 
 And i want use Another Service in Last Service Domain And Script File in Second Domain And Get CORS Error 
what Can I Do for Solve This problem 
I read Other Question About CROS And can't find Any Correct Answer

Answer (score 0):

To enable cross-origin requests,you have to add the [EnableCors] attribute to your Web API Project controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] // origins is your clients
public class YourController : ApiController
{

}
```

Comment: if i have web form application what can i do ?